# How to split a big Aggregate Root to smaller?

Tags: c#, .net-core, design-patterns, aggregate, domain-driven-design

I´m developing a domain layer that has a specific Aggregate Root.
That aggregate root consists of a Company that has various types of related persons. Something like this:

```
public class Company
{
   public virtual ICollecion<PersonType01Entity> Person01 {get; private set;}
   public virtual ICollecion<PersonType02Entity> Person02 {get; private set;}
   public virtual ICollecion<PersonType03Entity> Person03 {get; private set;}

   public void AddPersonType01(PersonType01Entity p) 
   { 
      if(Person01.Any(c => c.id == p.id )
         throw new Exception();
   }
   // more code
}
```

Imagine that I need to do this type of checking for every person type, and other invariants checks. My Aggregatte Root entity became to big and I´m do not know how to split it to be smaller.
Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand why you created an aggregate with many collections inside. I would have an aggregate called "Company" and another called "Person". And that each Person has a property with the type of person. And the Company has only one list with all Person.